# How to "svn ignore" a file, without overriding the existing ignore list

Tags: windows, svn

I'd like to ignore a bunch of files recursively in our enlistment, such as `/bin` and `/obj` and `*.user`.  I have a list of all these patterns in a file called `.svnignore` which is checked in.  I can recursively apply this ignore list to every directory like so:

> svn propset svn:ignore -R -F .svnignore .

I run this every so often when we add new projects and stuff.  However, now I want to ignore *just* the `/QEData` directory in the root (*not* recursive, just that *one* instance).  So, after running the above command, I then run:

> svn propset svn:ignore QEData .

However, *this* seems to wipe out all the patterns from `.svnignore` on the root directory and replace them with *just* the `/QEData` pattern.  How can I add to the ignore list *without* overriding the existing ignores on that directory?

**Note:** I'm looking for an answer that can be scripted on Windows and/or PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-interactive Windows-type propedit

```
echo NEWSTRING> PATH\TO\TEMPFILE
svn pg PROPERTY >> PATH\TO\TEMPFILE
svn ps PROPERTY -F PATH\TO\TEMPFILE .
del PATH\TO\TEMPFILE
```

Each such pseudo-pe will add two empty strings at the end of property-value list, empty lines are ignored SVN on processing anyway

**Note about global-ignore**

With

```
svn propget svn:global-ignores -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:global-ignores
    *.dat
```

and WC like

```
dir /B /S
z:\WC\a.txt
z:\WC\Sub
z:\WC\b.dat
z:\WC\Sub\c.dat
z:\WC\Sub\d.txt
```

with status

```
svn st --no-ignore
?       Sub
I       b.dat
```

I.e., in short - If into directory of WC with defined svn:global-ignores pattern added subdir and files in this subdir, matchng and not-matching pattern, TortoiseSVN on commit select *all needed* and *only needed* objects

[image: TSVN Commit]

Comment: Thanks!  Yea, I think the temp file would be the only solution to solve my original problem.  But it seems like `global-ignores` is the way to go for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Can this help?

```
echo -e "`svn propget svn:ignore`\nQEData" | svn propset svn:ignore -F - .
```

**Update:**

This can be a base for a script to append ignores

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo -e "Usage: `basename $0` <something to be ignored>\n"
    exit 1
fi

IGNORE=$1

echo -e "`svn propget svn:ignore`\n$IGNORE" | svn propset svn:ignore -F - .
```

Comment: Ouch, talk about a hack!  I can't believe the *ignore* functionality in Subversion is *this* bad!

Comment: ignore functionality in svn is not more than a property, sorry to tell you that :(

Comment: Which is fine, but there's no way to easily *append* data to an existing property, nor is there a way for properties to be inherited so every time you add new directories, you have to recursively apply your ignore properties again.

Comment: Also, this answer just adds the string *-e "`svn propget svn:ignore`\nQEData"* to my ignore list.  I'll keep messing around with this idea though, and update your answer if I get something working.

Comment: I think adding support for appending data to property values brings new issues like separators, new lines, etc. But you are right about the ignore property because it is a standard property and it deserves more care because it is the most used editable property

Comment: What is the problem of my single line solution?

Comment: @MikeChristensen "nor is there a way for properties to be inherited" - RLLY?! Read about inheritance in SVN 1.8+ and, specially, about global-ignores

Comment: @mmonem - Silly question, but is your solution designed for Linux or Windows?  I'm on Windows, and the one line solution doesn't work.

Comment: Oops! My solution is for Linux, sorry!

Comment: Oh should have been more specific!  Yes, I need a Windows solution.

Comment: Few minutes ago, I tried to help you by googling *batch file append string*. I had so many results that seem working. BUT... Windows batch files looks very ugly to me now however I used to use them heavily on my Windows was

Comment: @LazyBadger - Actually we *do* use inherited properties.  However, it doesn't work automatically.  You still have to *apply* the property to the root, which then sets the properly recursively on all existing objects.  Basically, the inheritance happens one time when the value is set.  It's more of an *apply this property recursively* type thing than an inheritance thing.  If you create a new folder somewhere, it doesn't automatically inherit the parent properties.  To my knowledge, 1.8 doesn't fix this (We're running 1.8.8, btw)

Comment: I've also been messing around with the `svn:global-ignores` property.  I remember trying it before, but it wasn't working last time.  Now it seems to do the trick.  I think now I can get rid of my ignore batch file.  I'm wondering if our repository got upgraded or something.